# How to select the previous version of a database element?

Tags: php, mysql

My database is setup like this

```
vid    title
 1     test
 2     test
 1     test2
 3     test
 4     test
 1     test3
 5     test
 6     test
```

Point is to get the previous version of something while deleting the last one. So I want to delete version 6 of `test` and get the previous version of it, which will be version 5. What is the PHP/MySQL-syntax for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM tbl WHERE title='test' ORDER BY vid DESC LIMIT 1;
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE title='test' ORDER BY vid DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select vid from table where title='test' order by vid desc  limit 2
```

so you will get last and the one before last in these two rows

and to delete

```
delete from table where vid = (select max(vid) from table where title='test')
```

Answer (score 0):

First delete the highest version:

```
delete from `table` where title = 'test' and 
vid = select max(vid) from `table` where title = 'test'
```

Then retreive the "previous" (now the highest version):

```
select * from `table` where title = 'test' and 
vid = select max(vid) from `table` where title = 'test'
```